# Google Nexus 7 not recognized via USB

Tags: nexus-7, windows, usb-debugging

I'm trying to connect my Google Nexus 7 to my PC for Android development but so far I've been unsuccessful.

I've tried connecting to my PC using different cables. When I connected the device to my Windows 7 PC, I didn't get any notification on Android or my PC that a device was connected. In "Other devices" my PC shows an Unknown device. I tried using MTP and PTP, as well as disabling and enabling USB debugging. I've used Nexus Root Toolkit, Universal Naked Driver, Nexus 7 toolkit, and I've tried [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjWjCQXlWDc) and many others and nothing has helped me.

I don't understand why there aren't any notifications on Android. Could it be a hardware problem? How can I check it?

Comment: Are using the USB cable supplied (with device), or an OTG type USB cable?

Comment: Can you see "Google Nexus 7 ADB Interface" in your device manager when you connect your device? I too had this issue and tried cleaning USB entries using the toolkit and installing driver from [Asus support page](http://www.asus.com/Tablet_Mobile/Nexus_7/#support_Download_32).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that:

- Your device is in USB Debugging mode
- You have the device drivers installed
- With the device connected, delete any 'Android' devices in the device manager. Do this by highlighting it and pressing the delete key.
- Disconnect then connect the device.

Comment: Yes, i enable USB debugging and install drivers. I can't understood why device didn't show any messages when i connect it.

Comment: @YuriyBugryn See edit

Comment: Doesn't help. My Windows 7 then looks (online) for the driver, but doesn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened the Device Manager and updated the driver. It looked for it online, and I just unplugged the Nexus and plugged it back in and it worked.

Comment: My Windows 7 doesn't find the driver or updates.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off my tablet and turned it on!Worked for me